# I want to show the form elements based on user selection

Tags: php

Based on the user selection I want to show the form elements.Here the user selects class1,class6,engg. How do I bring the all form element in one common form right know I am having different form and form field for class 1,6. I am struggling to solve this issue.I don't know How to fix this.

**My questions Are:**

1. If user select class1 I have list class1 form?
2. If User select class2 I have to combine class1 and class6 under one form.
3. Like wise user select class1,class2,class6,engg. I want to make all the form elments under one form.
4. I have given my output sample?

   **My FORM**

   ```
   <form name="frm" method="post">
   <table align="center">
   <tr>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" required ></td><td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Product</td>
   <td>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class1">class1
   <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class6">class6
   <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class8">class8
   <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class10">class10
   <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class12">class12
   <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="engineering">engineering
   <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="technology">technology
   </td><td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></td><td></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </form>
   ```

**My PHP VALUES**

```
   <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $name    = $_POST['txt'];
        $product = $_POST['chk'];
        print_r($product);
        foreach($product as $k=> $v)
    {
    if($v=="class1")
    {
    ?>
    <form name="f1" action="" method="post">
    <p>class1
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    }
    if($v=="class1" && $v="class6")
    {
    ?>
    <form name="f1" action="" method="post">
    <p>class1</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
    <p>class6</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
    <input type="text" name="name" value="">Tutor Name
    <input type="text" name="name" value="">Tutor Address
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    }
    }
    }
    ?>

**I want output like this:**For class1 form:
<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
<p>class1
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
****I want output like this:**For class1, class6 form:**
<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
<p>class1</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
<p>class6</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
<input type="text" name="name" value="">Tutor Name
<input type="text" name="name" value="">Tutor Address
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Like this the I want to make the form base on user selection.If user selected the all three classes(1,6,8), class 1 has different subject,like wise class 6 is different subject and engg has different subject.Now many problem is if user picks class(1,6,8),like wise class(1,6). How do I combine all the form element under one form and has one submit button

Comment: can any one help me out?

Comment: You can enclose your forms in `div` elements  or just assign them with id then use `show()` and `hide()` in JQuery.

Comment: ok how do i separate the foreach values .if i separate it is giving class1class2 even my if condition also not working there if we short out there we can bring the form in that condition

Comment: Use `if-else` conditional statement in your PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(count($product) == 1){
    if($product[0]=='class1'){
        echo "class one form";
    }else{
        echo "class other forms";
    }  
}elseif(count($product) == 2){
    if($product[0]=='class1' && $product[1]=='class6'){
        echo "class one and class 6 form";
    }else{
        echo "class other forms";
    }
}elseif(count($product) == 3){
    if($product[0]=='class1' && $product[1]=='class6' && $product[2]=='class8'){
        echo "class 1,6,8 form";
    }else{
        echo "class other forms";
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used else-if, somehow like this:

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $name    = $_POST['txt'];
        $product = $_POST['chk'];
        print_r($product);
        foreach($product as $k=> $v){

    if($v=="class1"){
    ?>
    <form name="f1" action="" method="post">
    <p>class1
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <?php 
    }
    else if($v=="class1" && $v="class6"){
    ?>
    <form name="f1" action="" method="post">
    <p>class1</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
    <p>class6</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="allsubject">allsubject
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="science">science
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="maths">maths
    <input type="text" name="name" value="">Tutor Name
    <input type="text" name="name" value="">Tutor Address
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <?php 
    }}}
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks  foreach is not separating the value .$v is always gives class1 value what we need to do here to completed this work

Comment: if i check class1 and class2 it shows Array ( [0] => class1 [1] => class6 .how do we match with