# Having issue in foreach?

Tags: php

Having issue in foreach. based on the checkbox  values I have list some form but here the problem is foreach is not separating the values.can any one guide what I have to change.where I have to change

```
<form name="frm" method="post">
    <table align="center">
    <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" required ></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class1">class1
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class6">class6
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class8">class8
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class10">class10
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="class12">class12
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="engineering">engineering
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="technology">technology
    </td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

**My PHP VALUES**


 <?php


     if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $name    = $_POST['txt'];
            $product = $_POST['chk'];
            print_r($product);
            $people = array("class1", "class6", "class8", "class10");
foreach($product as  $v)
{
   if (in_array($v, $people)) 
    {
        if($v=="class1")
        {
            echo "the class one is";
        }    
        else if($v=="class6" && $v="class1")
        {
            echo "the combiane class1 and class6";
        }    
    }
}
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: What is the result of your `print_r ($product);` ?

Comment: what error you have?

Comment: if I select  three checkbox  it show Array [0] => class1 [1] => class6 [2] => class8 )

Comment: your in_array function is outside foreach loop, due to that only last value stored in $v will be checked against people array. You need to move the in_array function inside foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=0; $i<count($product); $i++){
    if (in_array($product[$i], $people)) {
        if($product[$i]=="class1"){
            echo "the class one is";
        }else if($product[$i]=="class6" && $product[$i]="class1"){
            echo "the combiane class1 and class6";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks lot you have given the right answer. why i tried to do this please this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534555/i-want-to-show-the-form-elements-based-on-user-selection. and tellme where  are in i right way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$people = array("class1", "class6", "class8", "class10");
foreach($product as  $v)
{
   if (in_array($v, $people)) 
    {
        if($v=="class1")
        {
            echo "class1";
        }    
        else if($v=="class6")
        {
            echo "class6";
        }    
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3gn0vw)**

Comment: Hi not working .If I select four checkbox .it givesArray ( [0] => class1 [1] => class6 [2] => class8 [3] => class10 ) .It gives first value class1

Comment: Put your `if` condition in to `foreach` loop. displayed in my code. In your code if condition is out of `foreach` loop.

Comment: please understand if user check class1 and class6 it has to come class and class6. have you execute form html it is not coming properly.what about this condition if($v=="class1" &&  $v=="class6")
        {
            echo "class1 and class6";
        }

Comment: I updated  the question please and answer please that

Comment: `if($v=="class1" && $v=="class6")` is never true

Comment: How do you say like this user checks the class1 and class6 then the output has to come " combine class1 and class6" I am expection like this only because if see my html form it you can understand clearly next time user select class1 and class6 and class8 then i have show all three values

Comment: for what i trying to achieve .you can see this link.if you can help this is great     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534555/i-want-to-show-the-form-elements-based-on-user-selection/28536835#28536835